# Extracting shellcode from Wireshark pcap files

Tags: wireshark, shellcode

I running a honeypot for the telnet and ssh services (more specifically, I'm running cowrie).

When an attacker tries to download a binary file cowrie generally downloads it and saves it to a file, but sometimes it fails and displays the whole binary gibberish instead rather than saving it to a file.

I have the pcap files with the traffic though, so what I'd like to do is use some program to filter any downloaded binary code from the pcap file and save it to a file.

My question is, is there any such program/script that does that?

Comment: See google: https://www.google.com/#q=extract+files+from+pcap+files

Comment: Simple solution for you will be NetworkMiner.

Answer (score -1):

You can open the PCAP file with [NetworkMiner](http://networkminer.com), which will automatically extract all files that have been trasfered in clear text (HTTP, FTP etc). NetworkMiner woks in both Windows and [Linux](http://netres.ec/?b=142AA47).

Comment: He wants SSH and Telnet. For HTTP it's even built-in in Wireshark, why use an external tool?

Comment: @ThomasWeller He's running an SSH/telnet honeypot, but there's nothing in the post indicating that the downloads are done inside of the SSH/telnet session. Hackers often attempt to download tools for privilege escalation and persistence through HTTP or FTP and NetworkMiner supports both these protocols but not Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark: File / Export objects / HTTP